# Не удается вызвать browser.runtime.openOptionsPage() в FireFox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firefox-extension

Я создал браузерное расширение на VUE с помощью плагина [vue-cli-plugin-chrome-extension-cli](https://github.com/sanyu1225/vue-cli-plugin-chrome-extension-cli) и оно отлично работает в chrome.

Понадобилось сделать чтобы это расширение так же работало в браузере Firefox

Чтобы оно загрузилось в браузер мне понадобилось изменить в manifest `"background"`

для chrome было так:

```
"background": {
    "service_worker": "/background.js"
}
```

А для Firefox нужно так:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["/background.js"]
}
```

Теперь это расширение загрузилось в браузер и успешно открывается popup.html

В этом popup.html у меня есть ссылка

```
<a href="javascript:;" @click.prevent="openOptionPage();">Настройки</a>
```

Которая вызывает метод openOptionPage() который имеет такой код:

```
    openOptionPage: function (openModal = false) {
        browser.runtime.openOptionsPage();
        // chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();
    }
```

когда вызывается этот метод, в консоле вижу ошибки:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "InvalidStateError: An exception
> was thrown"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/view/popup.vue
>
> DOMException: An exception was thrown

> ```
> reactiveGetter VueJS
> openOptionPage popup.vue:205
> click popup.vue:211
> VueJS 35
> <anonymous> popup.js:8
> <anonymous> popup.js:14876
> <anonymous> popup.js:14877
> ```

пробовал разными способами - безуспешно!

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Манифест расширения для firefox так же отличается в части декларации страницы для настроек.

Вместо

```json
"options_page": "options.html",
```

Надо писать

```json
"options_ui": {
   "page": "options.html"
},
```

О правильности подхода свидетельствует то, что на странице `about:addons` появляется вкладка "Настройки" у вашего расширения. У меня в такой конфигурации только что заработало и клик по ссылке в том числе.

Answer (score 0):

Точно не могу назвать причину, но все решилось тем что я установил версию манифеста 2 вместо 3.